# Unable to fetch MySQL row data using PHP Program

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying for a workable program in which data should be fetched based on input ids and should be save as csv file format. Based on other's question, I wrote program but why it does not fetch the data?

```
<?php

   header("Content-type: text/csv");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.csv");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   header("Expires: 0");

   $dbc = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=experiment";
   $user = "katiee";
   $pass = "******";

   $dbo = new PDO($dbc, $user, $pass);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM clone WHERE id='001'";
   $qry = $dbo->prepare($sql);
   $qry->execute();
   var_dump($qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

   $data = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

   while ($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {    
      fputcsv($data, $row);
   }
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? To turn on error reporting use: `<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>`

Comment: 1.) for debugging remove header()... 2.) you will retrive the file .. **fputcsv()** write it to a file .. so you have to use echo in your loop .. 3.) when all run fine .. remove the var_dump()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no record asociated with `id='001'`. Try with "1".

Comment: Thanks @Karol.When i use a different table, it works. But the file "file.csv" is empty and contents are shown in browser like (array68) {["id]=>string(14)"001"["clone_date"]=>string(11)..How to  overcome it and save in the file?

Comment: If you don't need file on server hard drive, don't create file. Just set header with proper content-type and echo rows. Eventually you can fopen php://output.
Or, in current code close the file. And redirect user to it using `header('Location: ...url.../file.csv')`

Comment: @SeowooKim If this answer helped you solve the problem, tick it and close the question.